# Hardware for Surveying and mapping total station

Tags: gps, land-survey, total-station

Is "Microsoft Windows CE 6.0 / Magnet Field" operating system the sole property of TOPCON total station or it can be found in other total stations as well?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but "Microsoft Windows CE 6.0 / Magnet Field" is a combination of the base operating system (Windows CE 6.0) and Topcon's proprietary software "Magnet Field".

Windows CE is quite old and no longer [supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%20Embedded%20CE%206.0) by Microsoft.  You will find it still used in quite a few GPS devices, however.  Trimble's TSC3 still ships with Windows CE.

Magnet Field, I believe, would only be found on Topcon equipment.

One [interesting post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6acf3bb6-6371-44c4-85e4-bec966854c21/topcon-fc500-need-to-know-about-windows-embedded-handheld?forum=winembnatapp) found on a Microsoft forum indicates Topcon has full control over the software image and any adjustments would be cost-prohibitive.